# Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Invalid appcheck token.- Flutter IOS app

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check

I have used firebase realtime database in my flutter app. I am not able to login in my app, when i am running release build. It shows invalid app check token. While i can run it successfully in debug mode by following below link

[App Check with the debug provider on Apple platforms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/debug-provider)

I have also followed below two links for app check

[device check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/devicecheck-provider) , [app attest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/app-attest-provider)

Still i am getting invalid app check token for release build. Can anyone please tell me how to solve this error. Please check xcode screenshot.

[image]